# python app packaged for distribution

Tags: python, installation

I want to develop an app with WXPython or other GUI for Python,

can I use a packager for [Mac](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html) and [Windoze](http://www.py2exe.org/) that package all the necesary frameworks for my app to work?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have good experience rolling everything up using [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), and then packaging it all with [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).  There were good hooks to deal with hand-built libraries, matplotlib and data files.  The py2exe tutorial shows how to put them together.

This was a Windows solution -- Inno Setup is Windows only so it won't work on OSX for you.

Comment: py2app works perfectly for osx and it uses almost the same setup.py format. I use both py2exe and py2app, and even pyinstaller for linux